# simulating competing risks analysis

Tags: survival, competing-risks

Please could you help me to figure out how to simulate competing risks survival data?

I am aware that I can achieve this using survsim command but I would like to generate this from first principles.

The idea is to simulate a HR for treatment for the event of interest and then have a HR for treatment for the competing risk. I want to understand how much the HR from the cox regression is biased compared to the HR from stcrreg. In the code, I tried to assume minimal censoring but this can be modified later.

I have tried to do this with the following code but it does not seem correct. Could you help me figure out the correct code?

From my understanding this is a key paper explaining the algorithm for the competing risks simulation which I am struggling to understand

Beyersmann, Jan, Aurelien Latouche, Anika Buchholz, and Martin Schumacher. "Simulating competing risks data in survival analysis." Statistics in medicine 28, no. 6 (2009): 956-971.

Code:

```
clear
set obs 3000

gen treatment = runiform()>0.5

gen double u = runiform()   

// 2 represents the competing risk and 1 represents the event of interest
gen risk_events = runiform()>0.95 // competing risk, 50/50 chance
recode risk_events 0=1 1=2

tab risk_events

// the hazard for the event of interest
local mediantime = 12
local b_cons = -ln(0.5)/`mediantime' 
display `b_cons'
gen xb1 = ln(`b_cons') + ln(0.70)*treatment
gen lambda1 = exp(xb1)

// the hazard for the competing risk
local mediantime = 7
local b_cons = -ln(0.5)/`mediantime'  
display `b_cons'
gen xb2 = ln(`b_cons') + ln(1)*treatment
gen lambda2 = exp(xb2)

gen t = -log(u)/lambda1 if risk_events==1
replace t = -log(u)/lambda2 if risk_events==2

// censoring time
gen cens=runiform(1000,2000)

// generate a non-informative censoring indicator
gen event = 1        
replace event = 0 if t>cens    

gen t0 = 0
replace t0 = t if event==1

gen state1 = 1
replace state1 = risk_events if event==1
replace state1 = 0 if event==0
tab event state1, col

gen t1 = t               
replace t1 = cens if event==0

stset t1, fail(state1=1)

sts graph, by(treatment)

stcox treatment
stcrreg treatment, compete(state1==2)

************************
```